# What is the maximum amount of experience a unit can receive in each age?

Tags: civilization-5

To put it another way, how far through the experience tree can a unit progress in each age?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The amount is unlimited. You can have level 15 warriors in the ancient era, in theory.

You might have been confused by the fact that a unit with 30 XP or more cannot gain any XP from barbarians... but this is independent of era.

Comment: Hmmm... independent of barbarians you say... interesting.

Comment: Not sure this is correct, just had a unit at level 14, trying to level to level 15, and it wouldn't go beyond exactly 1k exp, I was attacking a city state, possibly against a player it would go higher, or it might just be early units have a cap, since it was a chariot still.

Answer (score 4):

Level 15 is the highest. You can keep gaining XP though.

[image: experience]

Comment: Is that the same for every different kind of unit?